# How to debug programs with "sudo" in VSCODE

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a program in VSCODE. The program needs to be launched as root or with "sudo" on Ubuntu. What's the best way to achieve this? An example launch configuration would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The only way to debug a process running as root is with a debugger running as root. This is a fundamental aspect of the POSIX security model. Vscode cannot do anything about it. So, you'll have to run vscode as root.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: At least when running on Linux, vscode does debugging by invoking a debugger (gdb or lldb) as a separate process, the path to which is specified as `miDebuggerPath` ain a file named `launch.json`. You can probably specify `sudo /usr/bin/gdb`, but you'll probably also want to use `--askpass` to specify an alternative way for it to get credentials, since the user probably won't be able to interact directly with `sudo` to authenticate.

Comment: [Relevant](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/launch.md).

Answer (score 35):

I have been in a similar situation recently-
I have solved it by adding {"sudo": true} in launch.json file under .vscode directory.

just added the following line in .vscode>launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "other..." : "configs...",
            "request": "launch",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "${file}"
            ],
            "sudo": true
        }
    ]
}
```

VS code version I'm using is -

> Version: 1.49.1 OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 64-bit

This appears to not work on all languages. For me it worked for python 3.x Other users reported it doesn't work for C/C++.

Comment: This not work when debuging C/C++ code, maybe for other languages? (OP didn't specify language)

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the language. It was Python 3.x

Comment: This worked for me on Python3.6 and using a remote machine.

Comment: In Go this is the "AsRoot" property

Comment: @iggy12345 in Go it's `asRoot` property and you have to combine it with integrated terminal like this `"asRoot": true, "console": "integratedTerminal",`

Answer (score 30):

I did the following:

1. create a script called "gdb" in e.g. my home directory, containing:
   `pkexec /usr/bin/gdb "$@"`
2. make it executable
3. modify the launch.json in VSCode to call the script (obviously change *username* accordingly) by adding "miDebuggerPath":

```
...
            "externalConsole": false,
            "miDebuggerPath": "/home/<username>/gdb",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
...
```

4. whilst debugging, use `top` or such like to verify the process is running as root.

That should be enough.

Comment: Super helpful.  If only I knew how to make pkexec remember my password!  Another note that is VSCode does not end the debug session if you cancel the prompt.

Comment: Does not work with passwordless key-based authentication.

Answer (score 19):

My solution:

add `/usr/bin/gdb` to `/etc/sudoers` like [here](https://linuxhandbook.com/sudo-without-password/)

add a executable file whose content is

```
sudo /usr/bin/gdb "$@"
```

set `miDebuggerPath` to the file

Comment: user_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/gdb. That worked. Yes, this sucks in that we added sudo for gdb. Security hole and all but I am working on a total local scenario with a Raspberry Pi which is an IoT device never going to production, so works for me.

Comment: This solution worked for me when working on a remote Ubuntu target. Just note that it is better to add _ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/gdb_ in a separate file in /etc/sudoers.d folder than changing the /etc/sudoers file

Comment: it works for my C++ project when working on a remote ubuntu server.

Answer (score 9):

Do not know the way to make vscode to run sudo gdb.
But you can sudo to run vscode so natually you can sudo gdb for debug.

> sudo code . --user-data-dir='.'

Comment: I am using visual studio code remote to edit code on a remote ubuntu server. Any idea How can I do the same?

Comment: This caused VSCode to freakout.

Answer (score 3):

**launch.json**:

```
{
    "miDebuggerPath": "${workspaceFolder}/gdb_root.sh"
}
```

**gdb_root.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
SELF_PATH=$(realpath -s "$0")

if [[ "$SUDO_ASKPASS" = "$SELF_PATH" ]]; then
    zenity --password --title="$1"
else
    exec env SUDO_ASKPASS="$SELF_PATH" sudo -A /usr/bin/gdb $@
fi
```

`chmod +x gdb_root.sh`

**main.c**:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    // accept signal from VSCode for pausing/stopping
    char *sudo_uid = getenv("SUDO_UID");
    if (sudo_uid)
        setresuid(0, 0, atoi(sudo_uid));

    printf("uid = %d\n", getuid());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for java, but maybe for other languages too:

When first running a debug session, VSCode creates a terminal called e.g. `Debug: Main`. Just open the terminal, press Ctrl+C, type`sudo su`, enter your password and next time the debug session will be launched from this terminal with root privileges

Comment: Unfortunately, it recently stopped working :(

Answer (score 1):

Very easy way to solve this for golang is to:

```
$ sudo chown root:$(id -g) ~/go/bin/dlv
$ sudo chmod u+s ~/go/bin/dlv
```

This way dlv will be executed as root.

> It is pretty much the same for other languages. ALlow the debugger to run as root instead of relying in other config files or wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

As from the previous answers I had to use the method with a executable file in the home directory like:
/home/youruser/gdbasroot

But I had to use the content:

> sudo /usr/bin/gdb "$@"

instead of gdbk because I couldn't get gdbk to work without prompting for a password (which didnt work as its called by vscode remote debuger). I did it according this post (the upvoted and accepted answer):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/542397/change-default-user-for-authentication

When using sudo you can issue a sudo command in the vscode terminal and from then on you can use the "sudo debugger" without the password. Otherwise vscode gets prompted and can't handle it.

Greetings