# Vscode/Cmake tools - how can I attach debugger to a program that requires root privillege?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I'm writing a program using C++ and Cmake that requires low access level - root privillege to run.
I tried googling around but I didn't found an answer.
As the debugger I'm using GDB and I'm launch it from cmakeTools "debug" button.

**Edit (solved):**
Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58206689/14780687 and add following in vscodes settings.json:

```
"cmake.debugConfig": {
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "/home/username/gdb",
    
},
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033311/how-to-debug-programs-with-sudo-in-vscode

Comment: Answer from the first post worked, thank you!