# VScode debugging: /dev/gpiomem Permission denied

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi

**Goal**: I want to set up the VScode debugging on Ubuntu with a Raspberry Pi 400.

**What I have done**: I am able to compile and run the program using `sudo ./program_name`. I have to run sudo otherwise I get permission denied error. I would like to not run VScode with root privileges as its generally discouraged.

**The problem**: When I launch the debugger (press F5) and I include `wiringPi.h`, I get the following error:

```
wiringPiSetup: Unable to open /dev/mem or /dev/gpiomem: Permission denied.
  Aborting your program because if it can not access the GPIO
  hardware then it most certianly won't work
  Try running with sudo?
[1] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-j40gmjsr.mas" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-vltmyj1b.a3g"
```

My launch.json file looks like this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
  
    ]
}
```

What should I be doing to be able to launch the debugger with my setup? Can I add something to the launch.json file?

Comment: If you need root privilege to run the program you will need the same to run the program under the debugger. Error message is telling you as much.

Comment: It is seriously discouraged to run VScode with root privilege. Hence the question if it can be done otherwise.

Comment: Googling around the issue it seems you need to add yourself to various groups to get the necessary permissions, groups gpio and kmem are suggested. But I'm certainly no expert. Take this advice with due caution.

Comment: @Misha it should be. No one sane would suggest such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gdb` does not have permission to open `/dev/mem` or `/dev/gpiomem`. There are two approaches you can go forward with.

## Option 1 -- Elevate GDB's permissions

Instead of running vscode as root (which was already suggested, and you rightfully pointed out this is generally a bad idea), you can run gdb from within vscode as root, by having it call `sudo gdb` to launch the debugger as compared to just `gdb`.

## Option 2 -- De-escelated `/dev/mem` and `/dev/gpiomem`

The other option is to give yourself access to `/dev/mem` and `/dev/gpiomem` without elevating your permissions. `/dev/gpiomem` is mostly harmless to give access to, but allowing non-root access to `/dev/mem` is a major security hole and not advisable. If it all possible, go with option 1.

To give your use permission to open those files, you may do one of two things.

1.) Add yourself to the owning group. `/dev/mem` is owned by the group `kmem`, so adding your main user to that group will allow you read access.

2.) Modifying file permissions. `sudo chmod ugo+xwr fname` will allow any user to read, write, or execute that file. This is generally insecure, but helpful if you activate it only for a moment to solve some issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is helpful! For option 1: how do I tell vscode (and potentially the launch.json file) to run gdb with sudo?

Comment: The easiest option would be to replace miDebuggerPath with `sudo /usr/bin/gdb`, but failing that, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033311/how-to-debug-programs-with-sudo-in-vscode

Comment: Thank you. While your first suggestion does not work, the link looks good.